# Share Image via Intent : Unable to find image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri, android-imageview

Am trying to share an image via share intent. But each time i try, it keeps saying it can't load / find the image. please help. here is the code i used.

```
      String link = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri");
            Uri uriToImage = Uri.parse(link);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Btw, i have successfully parsed the same Uri, on the same activity into an Imageview and it works.

Comment: what is the content of "link"? If it is a file path then use this. Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

Comment: Good to know that. :)